# Why is cURL with SSL not working when called directly from Apache Ant

Tags: ssl, ant, curl

I'm doing a get on a site with https. If I use curl in Apache Ant's `exec` task it fails complaining that "https not supported or disabled in libcurl"; however if I make the same call from Ant via the shell using sh -c, it works.

Here is my Ant target:

```
<target name="list-milestones">
    <echo>Via SH</echo>
    <exec executable="sh" dir="." failonerror="true">
        <arg value='-c' />
        <arg value='/bin/env' />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="sh" dir="." failonerror="true">
        <arg value='-c' />
        <arg value='/usr/bin/curl --config ${user.home}/.curlrc -k -X GET -H "Accept: application/xml" "https://www.assembla.com/spaces/milestones/all/tibant" -o "build/milestones.xml"' />
    </exec>
    <echo>Direct</echo>
    <exec executable="/bin/env" dir="." failonerror="true">
    </exec>
    <exec executable="/usr/bin/curl" dir="." failonerror="true">
        <arg value='--config' />
        <arg value='${user.home}/.curlrc' />
        <arg value='-k' />
        <arg value='-X' />
        <arg value='GET' />
        <arg value='-H' />
        <arg value='"Accept: application/xml"' />
        <arg value='"https://www.assembla.com/spaces/milestones/all/tibant"' />
        <arg value='-o' />
        <arg value='"build/milestones.xml"' />
    </exec>
</target>
```

and here is the output:

```
-sh-4.2$ ant list-milestones
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
Buildfile: /usr/share/jenkins/jobs/TIBant-07-Upload/workspace/build.xml
[TIBant-Build] LOADING: /usr/share/jetty/TIBant-Build.properties
[TIBant-Build] LOADING: /usr/share/jetty/build.properties
[TIBant-Build] LOADING: config/ci.properties
[TIBant-Build] LOADING: config/default.properties
   [TIBant] IMPORTED: tibant.xml
   [TIBant] TIBant Home: /usr/share/jenkins/jobs/TIBant-07-Upload/workspace/src/ant

list-milestones:
     [echo] Via SH
     [exec] HOSTNAME=ve.mbqblqmj.vesrv.com
     [exec] ANT_BIN=/usr/lib/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin
     [exec] SHELL=/bin/sh
     [exec] TERM=xterm-256color
     [exec] HISTSIZE=1000
     [exec] TIBCO_HOME=/opt/tibco
     [exec] ANT_HOME=/usr/lib/apache-ant-1.8.2
     [exec] ANT_OPTS=-Xmx128m -Djava.awt.headless=true
     [exec] JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx128m -Djava.awt.headless=true
     [exec] USER=jetty
     [exec] LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/../lib/amd64
     [exec] JETTY_PORT=8080
     [exec] JAVA_BIN=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_27/bin
     [exec] LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
     [exec] JETTY_USER=jenkins
     [exec] _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
     [exec] NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
     [exec] JENKINS_HOME=/usr/share/jenkins
     [exec] DESIGNER_BIN=/opt/tibco/designer/5.7/bin
     [exec] MAIL=/var/spool/mail/jetty
     [exec] PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/cfengine/bin
     [exec] PWD=/usr/share/jenkins/jobs/TIBant-07-Upload/workspace
     [exec] JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_27
     [exec] LANG=en_US.UTF-8
     [exec] XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
     [exec] HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
     [exec] SHLVL=2
     [exec] HOME=/usr/share/jetty
     [exec] LOGNAME=jetty
     [exec] LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
     [exec] DISPLAY=:0.0
     [exec] G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
     [exec] _=/bin/env
     [exec]   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
     [exec]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
     [exec] 
     [exec]   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
     [exec] 100 22852    0 22852    0     0  33357      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 34835
     [echo] Direct
     [exec] HOSTNAME=ve.mbqblqmj.vesrv.com
     [exec] ANT_BIN=/usr/lib/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin
     [exec] TERM=xterm-256color
     [exec] SHELL=/bin/sh
     [exec] HISTSIZE=1000
     [exec] ANT_HOME=/usr/lib/apache-ant-1.8.2
     [exec] TIBCO_HOME=/opt/tibco
     [exec] ANT_OPTS=-Xmx128m -Djava.awt.headless=true
     [exec] USER=jetty
     [exec] JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx128m -Djava.awt.headless=true
     [exec] LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
     [exec] JAVA_BIN=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_27/bin
     [exec] JETTY_PORT=8080
     [exec] JETTY_USER=jenkins
     [exec] _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
     [exec] JENKINS_HOME=/usr/share/jenkins
     [exec] PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/cfengine/bin
     [exec] MAIL=/var/spool/mail/jetty
     [exec] DESIGNER_BIN=/opt/tibco/designer/5.7/bin
     [exec] PWD=/usr/share/jenkins/jobs/TIBant-07-Upload/workspace
     [exec] JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_27
     [exec] LANG=en_US.UTF-8
     [exec] HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
     [exec] HOME=/usr/share/jetty
     [exec] SHLVL=1
     [exec] LOGNAME=jetty
     [exec] LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
     [exec] DISPLAY=:0.0
     [exec] G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
     [exec] LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/../lib/amd64
     [exec] NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
     [exec] XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
     [exec] 
     [exec] curl: (1) Protocol "https not supported or disabled in libcurl

BUILD FAILED
/usr/share/jenkins/jobs/TIBant-07-Upload/workspace/build.xml:509: exec returned: 1
```

I sorted and compared the environments and I couldn't find any significant differences.

This has got me stumped. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the extra double quotes `"` in the `arg` values. The following works for me.  The quotes are treated as literals, and passed through to curl - so it thinks the protocol you're attempting to use is `"https` rather than `https` as you intend.

```
<exec executable="/usr/bin/curl" dir="." failonerror="true">
    <arg value='--config' />
    <arg value='${user.home}/.curlrc' />
    <arg value='-k' />
    <arg value='-X' />
    <arg value='GET' />
    <arg value='-H' />
    <arg value='Accept: application/xml' />
    <arg value='https://www.assembla.com/spaces/milestones/all/tibant' />
    <arg value='-o' />
    <arg value='build/milestones.xml' />
</exec>
```

The `Accept...`, `https:...`, and `build/milesones.xml` are the changed arg values.

Answer (score 1):

Something is going wrong with Ant. I could reproduced your error with my MacOs and Ant 1.8.2.
And with this simple Java main, it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            new String[] { "/usr/bin/curl", "-k", "-X", "GET", "-H", "Accept: application/xml",
                    "https://www.assembla.com/spaces/milestones/all/tibant", "-o", "build/milestones.xml" });
    System.out.println(exec.waitFor());
    System.err.println(IOUtils.toString(exec.getErrorStream()));
    System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(exec.getInputStream()));
}
```

You're welcomed to open an issue in Ant's bugzilla: http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=Ant

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it indicates that it runs different curl executables (and thus different libcurls), as that message is what libcurl reports if you try to use a protocol that it wasn't built to support.

Make sure that there's no preceeding space before the "https" in the error text, as if it is the problem is exactly that: an initial white space in the URL.

Comment: Initially I also though it might be using different executables, which is why I'm using the full path `/usr/bin/curl` in both cases. I can also confirm the above is copy and past of the code and there is no preceding space.

Comment: Even if some hater -1 my answer, I will repeat that libcurl is the one that says the protocol XXX is disabled, and if it doesn't in one case and does in another it CANNOT be the same libcurl. Hate it or not.

Comment: IMO your answer is wrong and unhelpful, which is why I -1'ed it. That doesn't make me a "hater". If you still think you're right, please elaborate on how a non-visible space is involved, how `/usr/bin/curl` resolves to different executables or how different versions of libcurl are being used. I had the same thoughts when (except for the space) before I posted and tried to rule them out; I could explain the behaviour, hence my post.

Comment: so please tell me how the different calls end up using different versions of libcurl? because ultimately that is what the question is about. At the moment your answer just reminds my of the [Helicopter in Fog Microsoft Joke](http://www.elsop.com/wrc/humor/ms_helic.htm)

Comment: I don't claim to understand or realize *how* it would end up calling different versions (and I don't think we have enough data to tell), I'm just posing this as an explanation as to how you can get the output in one case and not in the other. The only other option I can think of would be that in one of the cases there's an additional option used that limits curl to what protocols to consider (with --proto).